# Dynamic grid with Item, Edit and Footer Template

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am using a gridview with ItemTemplate, EditTemplate and FooterTemplate as In My senario I want data input by client.

Client mark the multiple check boxes (suppose mark 4 checkboxes name IncomeTax, EOBI, PF and Late Arrival) and after selection when client presses a button then the below grid will display like

```
EmployeeCode | Name | IncomeTax | EOBI | PF | Late Arrival | Action
```

with footer.

When I insert data

```
001 | Jacob | 250 | 150 | 50 | 63 | Press save button
```

then that will display on itemtemplate and footer row will shown below for more input.

My problem is how I bind gridview with dynamic column including, Item Template, Edit and footer template? I have been stuck on this issue for the past 3 days :(

Comment: `FooterTemplate` will be visible once you have data in `GridView`. You only need to bind `ItemTemplate` data and `EditTemplate` is shown once a row status is changed to `Edit`.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the footer row to input new rows ?

Comment: party I make class but only showing line with not edit able :(

Comment: yes Symeon :) any help

Comment: get a mock up man? your question has no head and tail

Answer (score 0):

To add a new row in a gridview from the footer, i have used [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-vb) in the past . NB this is quite an old tutorial, and i remember one of the problems i have had with this is that the footer is only shown if you have data in the gridview so often i would have to put dummy data in the datasource if the GridView1.Rows.Count=0 in the GridView1.DataBound event.

HTH